# How to publish pages under a subdomain url?

Tags: pages, blog, subdomains, hierarchical

I have created a subdomain as:

> blog.example.com

How to put publish my pages as

> blog.example.com/page1
>   blog.example.com/page2

Comment: Do you have WordPress installed on your subdomain (blog.example.com)?

Comment: No, I am looking for the way to map my actually wordpress pages under my subdomain. For the subdomain itself, I can do it by this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ2VAhewOIo). But after that, I couldn't find an easy way.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be an 'easy' way to do this, other than to install another copy of WordPress to the subdomain and handle the pages separately through another installation... I'm not really sure why you would even want to do this in the first place...?

Comment: @mat the biggest websites which I compete against all doing the same thing. Check these links, all the same. [redbubble](https://blog.redbubble.com) , [threadless](https://blog.threadless.com/), [society6](https://blog.society6.com/), [customink](https://blog.customink.com/). I don't think this is very unusual.

Comment: All of the example sites that you provided have a different design/layout to their main domains. This suggests that they are using a different system for their blog domains, as per my suggestion above. The best way to achieve this would be to install a separate installation of WordPress in the blog subdomain.